# Is a mental health crisis defined anywhere in the Mental Health Acts?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, definition, mental-health

Does the state of mental health crisis have any statutory definition provided by the Mental Health Act 1983 or any other piece of legislation in the UK?

Comment: Not my DV nor VTC, and I'll offer an answer when I have more time

Answer (score 4):

**No**

The term "mental health crisis" is often used colloquially but it has no legal definition that I can find. In fact, the word  "crisis" does not appear at all in:

[Mental Health Act 1959](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/7-8/72/contents), the [Mental Health Act 1983](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1983/20/contents), the [Mental Capacity Act 2005](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/9/contents), or the [Mental Health (Discrimination) Act 2013](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2013/8/contents).

The 1983 Act, being the primary legislation in this area, uses "mental disorder" which it defines at [section 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1983/20/section/1?timeline=false) as:

> ...any disorder or disability of the mind